# behat/mink open window and take a screenshot of it

Tags: symfony, phantomjs, behat, mink

I am running a test on Behat where I click a button that opens another page and I would like to interact with that page (a screenshot to start with).

I tried something like this

```
public function iTakeAScreenshotOfTheNewWindow($filename)
{
    $windowNames = $this->getSession()->getWindowNames();
    $driver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();
    if(count($windowNames) == 1) {
        throw new \Behat\Mink\Exception\ExpectationException("No extra window found", $driver);
    }

    $lastWindow = array_pop($windowNames);

    $driver->switchToWindow($lastWindow);

    if (!$driver instanceof PhantomJSDriver) {
        throw new UnsupportedDriverActionException('This step is only supported by the PhantomJS driver', $driver);
    }

    $screenshot = $driver->getScreenshot();
    file_put_contents($filename, $screenshot);

    $this->getSession()->switchToWindow(); //back to main window

}
```

But I get the error

```
Could not find window handle by a given window name: 1 (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
```

Before I click on the button (and open the new window), a vardump of $windowNames shows:

```
array(1) {
     [0]=>
     string(1) "0"
   }
```

After the window has been opened:

```
array(2) {
     [0]=>
     string(1) "0"
     [1]=>
     string(1) "1"
   }
```

How can I change windows?

thanks

(Working on Symfony 2.8)

Answer (score 0):

For switching to the new window you can use something like this:

```
public function switchToNewWindow()
    {
        $wdSession = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession();
        $windows = $wdSession->window_handles();
        $this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToWindow(array_pop($windows));
    }
```

Comment: The method does not exist: Call to undefined method Zumba\Mink\Driver\PhantomJSDriver::getWebDriverSession()

Comment: Add this to the class that extends MinkContext.

Comment: That's where I added it :), but I got that error message

Comment: You can update the question if you have found/tried new things, also you should add also the error messages you are getting + other details like behat version, if you are using page objects.